# What is the proper way to handle navigation in a Flutter app? My troubled solutions do not work correctly

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-navigation

I'm a seasoned enterprise web app dev, but I'm new to mobile dev and have taken on learning Flutter for a personal project idea.  I am struggling with how to set up the proper navigation of my app.  I feel like there is some super simple solution to this problem, but I am not able to figure it out.

My navigation is based on a side drawer. Below are the different ways that I have tried and the issues I have had with them.  I'm hoping someone can give me some ideas or set me straight on the right path.

**Idea #1:** Using an `IndexedStack` widget as the body and then having each link in the `Drawer` change the current index.

Code:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> widgetOptions = <Widget>[Link1(), Link2(), Link3()];

  void onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (selectedIndex == index) return;
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primaryColor: Colors.red[800],
          accentColor: Colors.red[800],
        ),
        home: Builder(
          builder: (context) => Scaffold(
              extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                  color: Colors.red[800],
                ),
                elevation: 0,
              ),
              body: IndexedStack(
                index: selectedIndex,
                children: widgetOptions,
              ),
              drawer: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        MdiIcons.map,
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' Link 1',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[850]),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    onTap: () {
                      onItemTapped(0);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.person_add,
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' Link 2!',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[850]),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    onTap: () {
                      onItemTapped(1);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: Row(children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        MdiIcons.login,
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        ' Link 3',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[850]),
                      ),
                    ]),
                    onTap: () {
                      onItemTapped(2);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ))
              ),
        ));
  }
}
```

*The Good*: initially, this achieves exactly what I wanted

*The Problems*:

1. Eventually I came to learn that each widget listed in `widgetOptions` was instantiated, even if it was not used.  My years of experience have told me this is not efficient.
2. Navigating from one screen to another via `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ClassNameHere()));` causes the new screen to load 'overtop' of the existing content instead of 'inside' the main widget body and no longer shows the `AppBar` and `Drawer`.

*The Solution that I thought of and could not get to work*: I realized that the new screen was being loaded on it's own and not as the body of the main widget like the links in the drawer perform.  I thought that instead of using `Navigator.push()`, I just needed to call `onItemTapped()` in the main widget with the new page's index and it would work except I have no idea how to do that via the screen widget class and nothing I have tried from Google searches has achieved this for me.

So because of this, I decided to try the following...

**Idea #2**: I got rid of the `IndexedStack` and broke the `AppBar` and `Drawer` out into their own classes.  Then I made each screen class it's own entity and used the new `AppBar` and `Drawer` classes in each so, essentially, each screen was completely independent of the others.

*The Good*: I was able to navigate to each screen via the `Drawer` or `Navigator.push()` and could see the `AppBar` and `Drawer` as I expected

*The Bad*: Every navigation created a new instance of the new Screen and eventually I had a history of multiple instances of each Screen.  For example: I have a `Map()` screen that you can move around, place markers, etc.  If you navigate to another Screen and then use the drawer or a link to navigate to the `Map()` screen again, it's a brand new instance without all the changes you made.  You can use the `back` button, but that is not ideal.

*The Solution that I thought of and could not get to work*: My native language that I use everyday at work allows me to store instances of a class in memory so that I can retrieve that instance and use it later.  I thought if I could figure out how to do that, then every time the `Map()` screen is navigated to, I could look for an existing instance and return that, but I could not figure this out.

If anyone has any advice on how to make either of these Ideas work correctly or even an entirely new approach, I would greatly appreciate it!  Thank you!

Comment: Read this artiche https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31